# How to save one-many relationship data into core data using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a newsfeeditem and many users have shared this newsfeeditem.I need to save many users for one newsfeedItem.I had a one-many relationship from newsFeedItem to SlickUser.
but i don't know how I can save or relate SlickUser data to newsFeedItem. sorry im new to core data and im not able to save data using one to many relationship. if anyone can guide me how i can use SlickOwner to save data in newsFeedItem

```
for(int i =0 ; i < posts.user.count ; i++)
            {
SlickUser * user = posts.user[i];
                 if (self.contactdb) { 
                     [self.contactdb setValue:user.Aprovider forKey:@"Aprovider"];
                    [self.contactdb setValue:user.name forKey:@"name"];
                     [self.contactdb setValue:user.userid forKey:@"userid"];
  }
                else{

    NSManagedObject *newdevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SlickUser"  inManagedObjectContext:context];
                                  [newdevice setValue:user.Aprovider forKey:@"Aprovider"];
                                  [newdevice setValue:user.name forKey:@"name"];
                                  [newdevice setValue:user.userid forKey:@"userid"];
 NSError *error = nil;
                              if (![context sa[here is the image for newsFeedItem ][1]ve:&error])
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"can't save %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                              }
}
```

}
here is newsFeedItem Entity :

```
extension NewsFeedDataItem {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NewsFeedDataItem> {
        return NSFetchRequest<NewsFeedDataItem>(entityName: "NewsFeedDataItem")
    }
     @NSManaged public var aprovider: String?
     @NSManaged public var lid: String?
     @NSManaged public var owner: NSSet?
 }
xtension NewsFeedDataItem {

    @objc(addOwnerObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToOwner(_ value: SlickUser)

    @objc(removeOwnerObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromOwner(_ value: SlickUser)

    @objc(addOwner:)
    @NSManaged public func addToOwner(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeOwner:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromOwner(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

and this is UserSlick entity:

```
extension SlickUser {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SlickUser> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SlickUser>(entityName: "SlickUser")
    }
    @NSManaged public var aprovider: Int64
    @NSManaged public var userid: String?
    @NSManaged public var userPic: String?
    @NSManaged public var newsFeedPost: NewsFeedDataItem?
}
```

[this is the screenshort for slickUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptEPz.png)

Comment: Can you share more of what your model/entities are? The screenshot doesn't give enough information to help. It sounds like there are two entities setup like this: A 'Feed Item' has 1 owner, and many subscribers (both of which are a 'User' type). In that case, a 'User' would have a 2 to-many relationships to 'Feed Item'. One relationship as the owner of an item, and one relationship for their own subscriptions. Is that right?

Comment: @richardpiazza, i have edited the post and posted entities for userSlick and NewsfeedItem.a feedItem just have owners because many owners can share the same post. so owner and newsfeeditem have one to many relationships

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is additional relationships between your `SlickUser` and `NewsFeedDataItem`. You have a single **one-to-many** relationship defined between your *user* and *item* - `NewsFeedDataItem.owner -> SlickUser` - and the inverse of that relationship `SlickUser.newsFeedPost -> NewsFeedDataItem`.

Here's the assumptions I'm making about what you are trying to achieve:

- An *Item* is owned by a *User* [one-to-one]
- An *Item* can can shared by many *User* [one-to-many]
- A *User* can be the owner a many *Item* [one-to-many]
- A *User* can share many *Item* [one-to-many]

What is defined here represents four (4) relationships between your *User* and *Item*.

Here's how I've configured everything:

**NewsFeedDataItem**
[image: NewsFeedDataItem Entity]

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(NewsFeedDataItem)
public class NewsFeedDataItem: NSManagedObject {

}

extension NewsFeedDataItem {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NewsFeedDataItem> {
        return NSFetchRequest<NewsFeedDataItem>(entityName: "NewsFeedDataItem")
    }

    @NSManaged public var aprovider: String?
    @NSManaged public var lid: String?
    @NSManaged public var owner: SlickUser?
    @NSManaged public var sharedBy: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for sharedBy
extension NewsFeedDataItem {

    @objc(addSharedByObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToSharedBy(_ value: SlickUser)

    @objc(removeSharedByObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromSharedBy(_ value: SlickUser)

    @objc(addSharedBy:)
    @NSManaged public func addToSharedBy(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeSharedBy:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromSharedBy(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

**SlickUser**
[image]

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(SlickUser)
public class SlickUser: NSManagedObject {

}

extension SlickUser {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SlickUser> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SlickUser>(entityName: "SlickUser")
    }

    @NSManaged public var aprovider: Int64
    @NSManaged public var userid: String?
    @NSManaged public var userPic: String?
    @NSManaged public var userPosts: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var sharedPosts: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for userPosts
extension SlickUser {

    @objc(addUserPostsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToUserPosts(_ value: NewsFeedDataItem)

    @objc(removeUserPostsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromUserPosts(_ value: NewsFeedDataItem)

    @objc(addUserPosts:)
    @NSManaged public func addToUserPosts(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeUserPosts:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromUserPosts(_ values: NSSet)

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for sharedPosts
extension SlickUser {

    @objc(addSharedPostsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToSharedPosts(_ value: NewsFeedDataItem)

    @objc(removeSharedPostsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromSharedPosts(_ value: NewsFeedDataItem)

    @objc(addSharedPosts:)
    @NSManaged public func addToSharedPosts(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeSharedPosts:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromSharedPosts(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

- The `SlickUser.userPosts` is a set of *Items* that are owned by the *User*.
- The `SlickUser.sharedPosts` is a set of *Items* that the *User* has shared.
- The `NewsFeedDataItem.owner` is the owner of the *Item*.
- The `NewsFeedDataItem.sharedBy` is a set of *User* that have shared the *Item*.

For each of the relationship pairs *owner <> userPosts* and *sharedBy <> sharedPosts*, you will need to set at least one side of the relationship on your managed object. CoreData will manage the rest.

Does this solution address the needs of your project?